# Random Crashes with {insert random color here} Screen of Death

Tags: crash, hardware-failure

My computer occasionally crashes with various colors on screen. Afterwards, my computer doesnt start up before 3-4 reboots. There is no Graphics Card info, or Mem Count, it just doesn't start.

Actually the color depends on the last shown image on screen, for example when I'm browsing SO it's usually a white screen of death, or when I'm playing World of Warcraft duelling in Durotar it's brown, or green in FIFA99 etc.

- At first I thought it's RAM related, I have 2x2GB DDR2 ram blocks on my mainboard. I downloaded a memory test program, booted my PC with it and ran some tests, and there was some bad RAM blocks. I sent that faulty RAM to manufacturer and got a new one.  But,the crashes didnt stop.
- Then I moved my mind to power supply (I had power problems with my old PC). So I removed all nonessential parts (CDRoms, Backup HDD, got a extra power cord for my monitor, even removed one of the RAM sticks). Crash frequency is pretty low now, but its still happening.
- Then I thought may be it's some loose nuggets or wires. I dissambled my whole PC into bits and re-assembled, stil no luck.
- I already ruled out overheating graphic card possibility, because crashes can occur even at the password prompt while windows starting.

Sorry for the "end-user" explanation, but I'm really losing my mind.

Comment: Still sounds like a graphics card issue - just because the crashes happen early doesn't mean you can rule the card out.  If you've onboard graphics, remove the card and retest.  If not, you might need to borrow a card to test with.

Comment: Any crash dump files?

Comment: Either your CPU is overheating or you have a faulty motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

SOD ain't always related to hardware. Last time when my PC had some SOD's, they were due to buggy driver so I will ask you to update your drivers (Video card, and other drivers).

P.S: Also check your PC for any Virus.